# Formulário dinâmico em PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

preciso de um formulário dinâmico que opere da seguinte maneira:

A página deve gerar Y textboxes de acordo com um número Y que esteja no banco.
Meu raciocínio é o seguinte:

a. Faço o select no banco para ver o número
b. Faço um while ou um for com esse número para exibir os text
c. Faço um tratamento de strings para definir o nome dos texts (exemplo: text1, text2, text3, etc.)
d. Faço o caminho reverso para gravar os dados no banco.

Isso dá muito trabalho. Tem alguma maneira mais simples?

Para contextualizar: é um jogo de "bolão de futebol". O administrador cadastra os jogos em um dia (pode variar a quantidade de jogos), e no outro dia os usuários jogadores devem preencher os palpites (nos textboxes).

O que posso fazer para simplificar?

Comment: o que vc ja tem feito? Caso tenha algo feito e está com problemas em alguma parte especifica, poste o código referente a parte, para ser mais facil a ajuda-lo

Answer (score 0):

Crie os `input`s com o mesmo atributo `name` seguido de abre e fecha colchetes, desta forma no PHP você terá um array pronto em `$_POST` com estas informações, exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="palpite[]">
<input type="text" name="palpite[]">
<input type="text" name="palpite[]">
...
```

Se você sabe a quantidade exata de iterações monte os campos com `for`, se não sabe use `while`.

Ou seja, dos seus passos de A até D, só recomendo no passo C não fazer o tratamento de strings criando variações numéricas do mesmo name, ao invés utilize este padrão de abre/fecha colchetes para obter um array.